# pursuing PhD without relevant bachelor degree

Tags: phd, masters, united-states, university, degree

I have a bachelor degree in Business Administration and 4 years experience in this field, however I discovered that this is not what I want to do for the rest of my life, I'm interested in Geography and Geographic Information Systems (GIS). I went for a MSc in GIS but with my previous background I barely get a pass grade. Now I want to pursue a PhD in Geography, would it be possible to get an admission in USA universities? if yes I appreciate if you could give some names of these universities that accepting students with irrelevant experience and a low grade in Masters degree. Please note that my Bachelor Degree grade is second class with honor from a UK university also the MSc from UK university with the grade "Pass".

Comment: I have no specific example for USA uni.. but Check this one, it has some usefull information .. it will answer the first part of the question.. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28900/phd-in-gis-after-bachelor-degree-in-computer-science?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much, however Computer Science is somehow related to GIS, I think anyone with a BSc won't have a problem to get admission for a PhD in Geography but people like me with BA, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

From the research I found all I can say
This a list of [United States universities with GIS PhD programs](https://www.gradschools.com/doctorate/geographic-information-systems)

You have a MSc in GIS even with pass, just go ahead and submit your undergraduate transcript. The admissions committee will be expecting to see one (BSc Or MSc) and your application might be screened out before consideration simply because this transcript is missing.

The fact that you've had GIS master may help to overcome the bad impression left by your BSc (even in my way of thinking there is no bad impression). 
Having a good letters of recommendation and one or more publications (of high quality) will help a lot more.

You certainly need to address this matter in your application, mostly by highlighting your recent MSc in GIS and explaining what has changed in your life so that you are going to be the good student.